# Rounding decimals or fractions to the 16th with jquery

Tags: jquery, math, decimal, rounding, fractions

I'm using this code to convert decimals to a fraction:

```
Number.prototype.fraction=fraction;
        function fraction(decimal){
            if(!decimal){
                decimal=this;
            }
            whole = String(decimal).split('.')[0];
            decimal = parseFloat("."+String(decimal).split('.')[1]);
            num = "1";
            for(z=0; z<String(decimal).length-2; z++){
                num += "0";
            }
            decimal = parseInt(decimal*num);
            num = parseInt(num);
            for(z=2; z<decimal+1; z++){
                if(decimal%z==0 && num%z==0){
                    decimal = decimal/z;
                    num = num/z;
                    z=2;
                }
            }
            return ((whole==0)?"" : whole+" ")+decimal+"/"+num;
        }
```

This works, but has some issues that I can't seem to resolve. First, numbers with long (or endless) digits after the decimal kill the page so I've had to manually limit the input using `.round()` before utilizing it. Second, I need to be able to round the fraction value to the nearest 16th.

I realize this is an especially tricky problem, as I've discovered while trolling around Google for two days, but hopefully someone knows how to do it. I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Math.round( number * 16) / 16
```

For example:

```
Math.round(32578.8252789345798345987683476983476908347569873490867309487609875690860*16)/16
```

gives

```
32578.8125
```

Which is = 32578 + 13/16

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your round to nearest 16th. If so, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Aha! I see how that works now. I thought I would somehow need to manipulate the fraction parts, but this is super easy. Thanks!

Comment: No, you didn't, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to round the fraction value to the nearest 16th

Try creating an array containing numbers between `1/16` and `1` , using `Array.prototype.reduce()` , `for` loop, `Math.min()`, `Math.round()`

```js
var s = 1/16, d = [];

for (var i = s, n = 0; i < 1; i += s, n++) {
  d[n] = i
}

function f16(num) {
  return num
    .split(".")
    .reduce(function(a, b, index, arr) {
      var curr = +("." + b), j;
      for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (Math.min(curr, d[i]) === curr) {
          j = " " + (i + 1) + "/" + (d.length + 1);
          break;
        }
      };
      return j === 0 ? +a + Math.round(curr) : a + j;
    })
}

document.onchange = function(event) {
  document.querySelector("output").innerHTML = f16(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.1" />
<output></output>
```